# What's wrong with my flags?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

I've had two declined flags in a week.  In both cases, the question ended up closed.  I'm not sure whether the flags were declined before or after that.  I'm guessing after, meaning the mods found nothing to do with an already-closed question.

[The first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27237105/exploiting-python-2-7-raw-input) was declined as "flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention."  I (wrongly?) interpret this to mean "you should've voted-to-close instead," but I *can't* VTC.  What should I do in that situation?

This happens a lot, by the way; you gain access to the Triage review queue long before you gain access to VTC, and Triage prompts me to flag when I click "Unsalvagable."  It's either flag it or do nothing.  Maybe Triage should require VTC privileges.

[The second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27320557/why-are-there-errors-in-w3schools-tutorials) said "a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it," which I don't understand at all since the questioner was asking for help troubleshooting a website (which happened to be W3Schools, but still).  The question was closed as off-topic (as I noted above, this may well have happened before the moderator saw my flag).

In both cases, I chose to write out a reason rather than picking from the list.  I did this because none of the standard close reasons seemed to fit exactly and I wanted to ensure the moderator understood my concerns properly.  Should I not do this?

In summary, **how should I change my flagging behavior to avoid declined flags in the future?**  For that matter, is there even anything wrong with the occasional declined flag?

Comment: Writing out a custom reason causes ♦ moderators to need to handle it, while flagging to close does not (it goes into a queue).  Using a custom flag reason is your mistake here.

Comment: The second one you flagged with "The code that has failed is not the OP's code. We are not in a good position to troubleshoot it (though SuperUser might want to have a look?)", and I believe the moderator used the "no evidence to support this" because of your implicit suggestion that this be moved to Super User. I tend to process all migration requests at once, and that might have been what happened there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> In both cases, I chose to write out a reason rather than picking from
>   the list.

This is why they were declined. Mods are very busy people. The close system works without needing their expertise. Please do not flag as other (*needing mod attention*) to close questions.

> For that matter, is there even anything wrong with the occasional
>   declined flag?

If it becomes more than occasional then you may end up having a flag ban for a limited amount of time, and it's possible that your flags will not be reviewed. So yea, everyone who flags a lot gets some declined flags now and again. Just be sure to learn from your declined flags, and not keep doing the same thing or you may end up with undesirable consequences.